# GUI in Java for an Ocaml application

Tags: java, user-interface, ocaml

I m developing a GUI (in Java) for an Ocaml application. Whats the best way to communicate the two application.

Cheers.

Comment: There are not that many portable options. Sockets (the most portable thing), pipes (can be clumsy on Windows and alike), and that's it. Other IPC methods are too platform specific. As for a payload: I'd vote for an executable plain text protocol, but that's nothing but a personal preference.

Comment: Not to be nosy, but why are you developing a Java GUI for an Ocaml application?

Comment: Original the tool is developed in Ocaml. Looking around, it doesn't seem to exist an OCaml GUI library that can work in different platform. GTK is awful. Hence, the solution to do it in Java.

Comment: You might consider working with another language which can be more easily linked to Ocaml.  Like C++ or Python+Pycaml or C#+F# (if the code can be compiled in F# as much, but not all Ocaml code can)

Comment: I vote for C++ which can easily interact with OCaml code, and you have a plenty of good GUI libraries.

Comment: compared to C++ GUI libraries, ocaml+lablgtk is just godsent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say what your target environment looks like.

If it's a standard desktop or server environment you could use a loosely coupled approach where the GUI and app are separate processes communicating by any convenient IPC method.

For a more tightly coupled approach I can think of two ways that might work.  One, you could compile your OCaml and run it as native code alongside the JVM using the Java Native Interface.

Two, you could compile your OCaml into JVM bytecodes using OCaml-Java: http://ocamljava.x9c.fr/

Disclaimer: I have only read about these approaches, never tried them.  And of course there could be other ways to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation as of Nov 2011 would be JSON as a serialization format over zeromq as a transport. The obvious disclaimer about "I'd need more info to give a better answer" applies.

JSON is simple and a widely supported standard. Zeromq is an abstraction of what sockets do that should transparently be able to communicate between two processes written on different platforms/stacks, without having to deal with low level issues like buffering when dealing directly with sockets.

On the OCaml side, the Caravan zeromq binding looks best.

https://github.com/bashi-bazouk/Caravan

On the java side, whatever is recommended on the Zeromq site.

For JSON, there is a decent JSON library for Ocaml:

http://martin.jambon.free.fr/yojson.html

But JSON is so trivial you may just write your own naive parser if the data types you'll send back and forth are relatively small.

JSON on the java side I don't have a recommendation but there are many libraries.

Thrift, Avro, or Google ProtoBuffers would probably be faster than JSON in their binary form, but the risk in those is whether the Ocaml bindings are in decent shape (I personally have no idea if they are).

Answer (score 0):

JSON and sockets is the solution I have chosen to communicate between Ocaml & Java.

On the OCAML side, I use Martin Jambon's [atdgen](http://mjambon.com/atdgen), which is a JSON serializer/deserializer based on the Yojson library. "atdgen" generates a parser and a printer from an .atd type definition file:

On the JAVA side, I use Jackson library and Jackson annotations to specify the JSON format.

As for sockets, I use just standards sockets library in Ocaml and JAVA.

And this solution works fine both on Unix and Windows OS.

Another solution would to be use [google protocol buffer](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) and the Ocaml piqi tools. It  should be more performant and safer as the ".proto" file can be used to generate both java code and Ocaml code.
Did anybody tried this solution ?